# Color change of fixed/sticky position object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen [this page](https://www.wix.com/html5en/hiker-create?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=600576476) (chrome version) and I am wondering about that circle that goes down and changes color. I am trying to do something similar myself and I am stuck in the **transition from pink-circle with orange background to green-circle with white background**. I have tried 2 strategies.

**A)** 
using **position: sticky; + hidding one layer under another and coordinating appropriately**, see code below. The problem is that this only works for one of the circles (the one "appearing") but no the "hidding" one; so the effect is not the same.

```css
.yellowbanner {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: sticky;
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  .orangebanner {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 21;
    position: sticky;
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  .greenbanner {
    background-color: mediumspringgreen;
       height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    top:500px;
    left:0px;
  }
  .bluebanner {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
  }
  .redbanner {
    background-color: white;
    height: 3000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DevProject</title>
  <link href="./resources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
    
  <div class="greenbanner"><div class="yellowbanner"></div></div>
  <div class="redbanner"></div>
    <div class="bluebanner">
        <div class="orangebanner"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**B)** Using **position: fixed; + some JS**. However all I have found would change the color (at a certain moment) of the entire circle, and not just the appropriated section of it.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. If you run the code snippet (large) u will see that the yellow circle reaches the bottom of the green area and then an orange circle appears in the blue area. Compare this to the web page I linked at the beginning of my question, concretely at the moment when the circle gets from pink to green. In that case it seems the circle just changes color when crossing to the white section. I would like to know how to do that (at least a tip on whether look for some JS or keep fighting with CSS). Thanks